# Is it possible to capture user-submitted video and add a 'title slide'?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

We're a non-profit that captures short oral histories. We're looking for

1. a way to have anyone submit their own short video on our youtube channel via our site and
2. briefly show our logo before each video begins (users would be notified and consent to this image being added). Is this possible in any way--through YouTube API, etc?

We don't have a ton of programming know-how but are trying to see if there's any way to auto-add our logo or a title screen to videos uploaded by others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solicit videos via [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/).

For adding a slide, you'll have to do it before recording the video.